# Can not Call Method.POST

Tags: xamarin, restsharp

I'm trying to implement restSharp in Xamarin in PCL part. But when I try to implement it, I get Stuck because my class can not call Method.POST/Method.GET. I've installed Restsharp Portable for PCL. Is there another thing that I must add to my project? Thank you.

here is the problem. I can't call Method.POST.
var request = new RestRequest("resource/{id}", Method.POST);

Comment: What do you mean by can't call? Do you get an error?

Comment: It seems like my project doesn't recognise Method.POST.

Comment: And again I don't understand. What do you mean by "doesn't recognise"? Does it call GET instead of POST?